# error : Name "main::outFile" used only once

Tags: perl

I a problem with my perl script:

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $out = "result2.txt";
open outFile, ">$out" or die $!;
my %permitted = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'f1.txt';
    map { /(.+?)\s+\(/, 1 } <$fh>;
};

open my $fh, '<', 'f2.txt';
while (<$fh>) {
    my ($phrase) = /(.+?)\s+->/;
    if ($permitted{$phrase}) { print outFile $phrase ;}
}

close outFile;
```

The error is :

```
Name "main::outFile" used only once: possible typo at teeest.pl line 14.
```

Any idea please?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

`print` has a very special syntax. Without `use autodie`,

```
print outFile $phrase;
```

means

```
print *outFile $phrase;
```

But the `print` replacement `use autodie;` creates can't quite reproduce that. It probably ends up being

```
print "outFile" $phrase;
```

which still does the right thing, but hides the use of `outFile` from the "used only once" warning checker.

The warning is spurious and harmless in this case. You can prevent it from being emitted by avoiding the unwarranted use of a global variable.

```
open my $outFile, ">$out" or die $!;
print $outFile $phrase;
close $outFile;
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem that is with "my ($phrase) = /(.+?)\s+->/;"  the content is only the segment of word before "->", but i want taht it print all the line "hello all -> salut (0.5)"

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to mention any of that. The string against which you are matching is `$_`. That's what you should be printing if you want to output the whole string.